# Composer - Vendor folder inside vendor folder - Class not found

Tags: php, composer-php, vendor

the project structure I have is like the following:

```
-src
-vendor             // from now on vendorA
-- module1
--- vendor          // from now on vendorB
---- module2
-Public
--index.php
```

I try to install a further module in **vendorB**, with composer require. After installation everything seems ok (composer.lock gets updated, module2 folders are being created etc.). But when I run the code, I get a "Class not Found" error (the error refers to the class from module2, when I try to initialize it).

I run composer require and composer update on **vendorB** level. Is there something more I could do?

Comment: Dependencies should not have their own `vendor` directory - all dependencies should be installed in one `vendor` directory on project level. I'm not sure why you would need to run `composer update` on vendorB level.

Comment: Why **exactly** do you want to use this structure?If you want to stick to it, please share more details

Comment: It is an existing structure in my new working place, not exactly ideal if you ask me, but still there is little to nothing I can do about it at the moment. In more details, the main app has the vendorA, where inside it, there is the module1, which is a custom module (not exactly a microservice, but lets say it is something close to it) with it's own repository and functionality. The point behind it is that module1 shall be shared among various projects/apps. I need to install phpspreadsheet to it (vendorB), but as said "class not found". I hope it is somehow clearer now.